# Can I and Should I test fireEvent and Handlers method in GWT?

Tags: java, unit-testing, events, gwt, junit

I am writting test for GWT, but I did not find any example of `fireEvent` test.
Can any one help me?

I have event that has handler which put some current variable on the list. I would like to test the method that fires an event?

Does this make any sense to anyone?

Do we need such Unit tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would split up the tests

1. Test if the event is fired
2. Test the method that puts a variable on a list by just calling the method directly

Regarding 1: You can use `com.google.gwt.event.shared.testing.CountingEventBus` and then use `getCount(GwtEvent.Type)` to check how many times the event was fired, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431131/mocking-gwt-eventbus-with-mockito) for more infos.
If you pass data in your event object and you want to test that you can create your own fake `EventBus` (see [this](https://github.com/timeu/GWA-Portal/blob/master/genophenbrowser-client/src/test/java/com/gmi/nordborglab/browser/client/testutils/RecordingAndCountingEventBus.java) and this [test](https://github.com/timeu/GWA-Portal/blob/master/genophenbrowser-client/src/test/java/com/gmi/nordborglab/browser/client/mvp/widgets/facets/FacetSearchPresenterWidgetTest.java#L102) for more infos)

You can also test that the your handler is properly executed when you fire the event. Just fire the event on the `EventBus` and use an assertion for the list (see [this test](https://github.com/timeu/GWA-Portal/blob/master/genophenbrowser-client/src/test/java/com/gmi/nordborglab/browser/client/mvp/ApplicationPresenterTest.java#L67) for an example)